# Apply format to just a part of the replaced text

Tags: vba, ms-word, find-replace

I want to add a soft hyphen after a slash in my word documents AND that soft hyphen should have a particular format (e.g. Font.Spacing = -100 and a white font color).

Search and replace "/" with "/^-" does only the first part of the job. The slash should not be formatet like the hyphen.

Just make a second search and replace with "^-" does not work, because a normal hyphen sould not get this special format - only the soft hyphen after a slash should.

My code so far to replace the slash:

```
Sub ReplaceSlash()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "/"
        .Replacement.Text = "/^-"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have other soft hyphens (not after a slash) in the document?

Comment: What code have you tried to solve this? IT would be possible, by manipulating the Range or Selection result of the Find. Lots of code sample here and elsewhere demonstrate how to do that...

Comment: Yes, there are soft hyphens NOT after a slash. They must not be affected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-Word VBA, Regex, replace format only of first capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489345/ms-word-vba-regex-replace-format-only-of-first-capturing-group)